# React Native: Call pointerEvents on both parent and child views

Tags: reactjs, react-native, event-handling, dom-events

### Background

I'm developing a heatmap component in React Native which is essentially a `<View>` that responds to `pointerEvents` provided by the user. The `children` are extracted from `this.props` and passed into the view.

```
<View
    style={s.overlay}
    onLayout={this._onLayout}
    onMagicTap={this._onDoubleTwoFingerTouch}
    onAccessibilityTap={this._onDoubleTouchAccessible}
    onStartShouldSetResponder={this._onTouchStart}
    onResponderMove={this._onTouchMove}
    onResponderReject={this._onTouchCancel}
    onResponderTerminate={this._onTouchCancel}
    onResponderRelease={this._onTouchEnd}
    pointerEvents={'auto'}
>
    {children}
</View>
```

### Problem

The view receives all touch events as long as there is no touchable component (like a `<TouchableOpacity>` component)  beneath it. Obviously then, the child component responds to the `pointerEvents`.

I already know how the `auto`, `box-none`, etc. `pointerEvents` enums operate, but I have not found the right combination or trick in order to trickle down these events from parents to children.

### TL;DR

How can I respond to `pointerEvents` in **BOTH** parent and the child components on a user's press?

Comment: Did you find a solution / workaround? I'm facing a similar issue...